# Two perl formats on a page

Tags: perl

I have inherited perl code that uses formats twice in rapid succession.  Here's a MWE.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use FileHandle;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub table {
    my ($name, $val);

    format_name STDOUT "FMT1";
    format_top_name STDOUT "FMT1_TOP";

    ($name, $val) = ("Item1", 42);  write;
    ($name, $val) = ("Item2", 100);  write;

format FMT1_TOP =
Name         | Cost
-------------+-------
.

format FMT1 =
@>>>>>>>>>>> | @<<<<
$name,         $val
.
}

print "Data 1\n"; table; print "\n";
print "Data 2\n"; table;
```

The problem I'm seeing is that perl obviously thinks both sets of data are part of the same table and doesn't print a new table heading.  So the output I get is this:

```
Data 1
Name         | Cost
-------------+-------
       Item1 | 42
       Item2 | 100

Data 2
       Item1 | 42
       Item2 | 100
```

I expected to see:

```
Data 1
Name         | Cost
-------------+-------
       Item1 | 42
       Item2 | 100

Data 2
Name         | Cost
-------------+-------
       Item1 | 42
       Item2 | 100
```

I'm sure there must be some `close_format`-like function that I'm missing at the end of `table()`, but formats are so last century that I've forgotten what I once knew about them, and all the examples I can find online use just a single format per program.  What am I missing?

Note that replacing formats with something else is not a viable option in this project at this particular point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`_TOP` is a type of page header. Perl interpreter prints it at the top of filehandle.

Use `$~` to tell the Perl interpreter that `FMT1_TOP` is the print format that should be used when calling `write`.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use FileHandle;
use strict;
use warnings;

sub table {
    my ($name, $val);

$~ = "FMT1_TOP";
write;
    format_name STDOUT "FMT1";
    format_top_name STDOUT "FMT1_TOP";
    ($name, $val) = ("Item1", 42);  write;
    ($name, $val) = ("Item2", 100);  write;

format FMT1_TOP =
Name         | Cost
-------------+-------
.

format FMT1 =
@>>>>>>>>>>> | @<<<<
$name,         $val
.
}

print "Data 1\n"; table; print "\n";
print "Data 2\n"; table;
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure how that answers my question.  Can you be a bit more explicit about what is missing from my code?  What do I need to cause top-of-form processing to happen for the second table?

Comment: It's a type of header which `perl` interpreter prints at the top of STDOUT. Once.

Comment: OP seems to be aware of that, and uses it for exactly that. But they want to use it more than once.

Comment: So are you saying that once a program has written a format to STDOUT, it can never write another one and still get top-of-form processing?  I know that cannot be the complete picture, because the code does it successfully in many places.   But I can't see how bits of code that work differ from my MWE above, other than that in the working cases, the uses of format are very well separated.

Comment: I see. But I have no idea why this works. :D After all, `$~` is the same as using `format_top_name`. But this seems to be a better option than mine though.

Comment: The name of the forma is entirely irrelevant.  Changing it from FMT1_TOP to ENDING doesn't make any difference.  What *does* fix it, and is the part of your code that you don't discuss at all, is setting `$~` and calling write explicitly on the top.

Comment: @RichardSmith: Exactly. I noticed that and removed that part.

Comment: Okay.  I've accepted this answer now, though I still have no idea why it works.  As @simbabque says, setting $~ is supposedly the same as calling format_top_name. Also, the extra form feed that his $- solution gives is a problem in this particular case.

Answer (score 2):

The `_TOP` format will be written at the top of every page. You can force a new page by setting `$-` to 0. Unfortunately that gives you a [form-feed character](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Page_break#Form_feed) (ASCII character 12 in decimal). If this only goes to the screen, it's probably not a problem.

This is documented in [`write`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/write.html) in the second paragraph.

> Top of form processing is handled automatically: if there is insufficient room on the current page for the formatted record, the page is advanced by writing a form feed and a special top-of-page format is used to format the new page header before the record is written. [...] The number of lines remaining on the current page is in variable $- , which can be set to 0 to force a new page.

This is how you can do it:

```
sub table {
    my ($name, $val);

    $- = 0; # <-- here

    format_name STDOUT "FMT1";
    format_top_name STDOUT "FMT1_TOP";

    ($name, $val) = ("Item1", 42);  write;
    ($name, $val) = ("Item2", 100);  write;

format FMT1_TOP =
Name         | Cost
-------------+-------
.

format FMT1 =
@>>>>>>>>>>> | @<<<<
$name,         $val
.
}
```

The output in my IDE displays the character.

[image: screenshot of output in Komodo IDE X]

My terminal does not. It shows a new line instead. But a printer would understand this to be a new page.

```
Data 1
Name         | Cost
-------------+-------
       Item1 | 42
       Item2 | 100

Data 2

Name         | Cost
-------------+-------
       Item1 | 42
       Item2 | 100
```