# what to do to remove error in following script

Tags: perl

I am new to perl .I am getting an error when I am trying to define second format after first one .please go through to my script and point out to me what mistake I have made and help me to resolve that error.

sometimes I am also getting error that header 'abc_top' is not defined.why so?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
format EMPLOYEE =
===================================
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<< 
$name $age
@#####.##
$salary
===================================
.
format EMPLOYEE_TOP =
===================================
Name                    Age
===================================
.
select(STDOUT);
$~ = EMPLOYEE;
$^ = EMPLOYEE_TOP;
$= =8;
$n="prateek";
$a="24";
$s="31500.00";
$name = $n;
$age=$a;
$salary=$s;
write;
format abc_Top=
----------------------------------------
name
----------------------------------------
.
format abc=
@|||||||||||||||||||||||||
$name
.
select(STDOUT);
$~=abc;
$^=abc_top;
$na="ankur";
$name=$na;
write;
```

expected result:header of second format should be present .

actual result:

```
===================================
Name                    Age
Salary
===================================
===================================
prateek                 24
 31500.00
===================================
          ankur
Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at main.pl line 5.
```

Comment: This is very bad code. Please start by adding `use strict;` `use warnings;` at the top of your code and fix all the errors / warnings that you get

Comment: See also [Two perl formats on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041051/two-perl-formats-on-a-page)

Comment: I strongly recommend using [Perl6::Form](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Perl6::Form) (a module for Perl 5) instead of the builtin forms.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, I have used formats exactly once in almost twenty-five years of writing Perl code. People just don't use them. Whatever it is that you're doing, you can almost certainly do it more easily without formats.

Secondly, let's look at that first error message:

> Use of comma-less variable list is deprecated at main.pl line 5.

And your line 5 is:

```
$name $age
```

That looks a lot like a list of variables to me. And it's certainly comma-less. So perhaps a good first attempt at fixing the problem would be to add a comma.

```
$name, $age
```

And, yes, that fixes the error. You could also have looked at the examples in [the documentation](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlform.html) and seen that every list of variables in a format definition has the variables separated by commas.

> sometimes I am also getting error that header 'abc_top' is not defined.why so?

Presumably, because you seem to use 'abc_top' and 'abc_Top' interchangeably.

I'm not sure about your final problem. But I'm pretty confident that it will go away if you fix the many problems that you'll find if you add `use strict` and `use warnings` to your code.

**Update:** Actually, my last paragraph was wrong. I mean, yes, you should still fix those issues. But that's not going to fix your main problem.

The problem is that you've already printed a page header format (`EMPLOYEE_TOP`) at the top of your output page. So Perl won't print another until it thinks you're at a new page.

The easiest way to trick Perl into thinking that is probably to set `$-` (the number of lines left on the current page) to zero. So add this line just before your second call to `write()`.

```
$- = 0;
```

Comment: As a counterpoint, I use formats for formatted output fairly often; they're nicer than `printf` for anything non-trivial. Also handy for easy word wrapping, especially of multiple columns.

Comment: @Shawn: You might well find that [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) is even better.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that worked for me:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($name, $age, $salary);

format EMPLOYEE =
===================================
@<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< @<< 
$name, $age
@#####.##
$salary
===================================
.
format EMPLOYEE_TOP =
===================================
Name                    Age
===================================
.
select(STDOUT);
$~ = "EMPLOYEE";
$^ = "EMPLOYEE_TOP";
$= =7;  # <- Page length. A new top of page format is printed for each page.
my $n = "prateek";
my $a = "24";
my $s = "31500.00";
$name = $n;
$age = $a;
$salary = $s;
write;

format abc_Top =
-----------------------------------------
name
-----------------------------------------
.
format abc =
@|||||||||||||||||||||||||
$name
.
#$- = 0;  # <-- Set this to zero to force a new page (so top of page format is printed)
$~ = "abc";
$^ = "abc_Top";
my $na = "ankur";
$name = $na;
write;
```

**Output**:

```
===================================
Name                    Age
===================================
===================================
prateek                 24
 31500.00
===================================

-----------------------------------------
name
-----------------------------------------
          ankur
```

See also [Perl6::Form](https://metacpan.org/pod/Perl6::Form) for more advanced formatting.